# Cant figure out why function returns "None"

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm trying to write a function for class that takes a string and goes through each character in it, every time it encounters an 'a' 'b' or 'c' it should add 3 5 and 7 to the "value" variable (ie. a=3 b=5 and c=7). Then at the end of the string I need to return the remainder of value%11.

this is what I have so far:

(ps. all the print statements in the hash_func are just so I could see what was going on)

```
def hash_func(string):
    value=0
    string_length= range(len(string))
    for i in (string_length):
        current_charecter= string[i]
        print (current_charecter)
        if current_charecter== 'a':
            value=value + 3
            print (value)
        elif current_charecter== 'b':
            value=value + 5
            print (value)
        elif current_charecter== 'c':
            value=value + 7
            print (value)
        elif current_charecter!= 'a' or 'b' or 'c':
            value=value+0
        else:
            value=value%11
            print (value)



print(hash_func("banana")) #this is the call to the function that is given by the grader, it should equal 3
```

and the funtion returns:

```
b
5
a
8
n
a
11
n
a
14
None
```

(It just returns "None" w/o the extra print statements)

So I know it is adding the values and skipping the letters that arent a b or c correctly, I just cant seem to figure out where the "None" is coming from.

As I understand it the none value is returned when a function or variable doesn't contain anything so Im not sure why it's being returned after my function executes everything (mostly) correct.

If anyone can decipher my code and tell me the stupid mistake I'm making I would be very grateful!

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Comment: Sorry but you can not do that :D, people have taken time to answer, to create useful content for others., you need to follow the proper route as linked above.

Comment: Plus no one is going to copy this work. They may copy the answer's work, but not the question's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question, your function returns nothing, hence `None` is returned by default.

Also note you code is wrong, here is the explanation

```
def hash_func(string):
    value = 0

    # It will iterate over the chars in the string and set ch to each char in
    # turn
    for ch in string:
        if ch == 'a':
            value += 3  # same thing as value = value + 3
        elif ch == 'b':
            value += 5
        elif ch == 'c':
            value += 7

        print(ch, value)

        # You don't need this and it's wrong also (note 1)
        # elif ch != 'a' or 'b' or 'c':
        #    value += 0

    # After you've iterated over the string, only then do you modulo it.
    # Otherwise you're performing a modulo every time you run into a character
    # that's not 'a', 'b' or 'c'
    return "Hash is " + str(value % 11)

print(hash_func("banana"))
```

**note 1**: When you have an `if statement` you use the `else` to match on anything that doesn't match the previous conditions. If you check if `ch == 'a'` there is no need to check `ch != 'a'`.

Also, doing

```
ch == 'a' or X or Y
```

does not do what you think it does.

What it's actually doing is

```
is ch equal to 'a'? Yes, ok condition is true
otherwise, is X true? or condition is true
otherwise, is Y true? or condition is true
otherwise condition is false
```

see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not

If you wanna check if `ch is one of 'a', 'b', or 'c')` you can use something like, `ch in ('a', 'b', 'c')`

Additionally for your reference,

```
def better_hash_func(string):
    values = {'a': 3,
              'b': 5,
              'c': 7}
    value = 0
    for ch in string:
        if (ch in values.keys()):
            value += values[ch]
    return "Hash is " + str(value % 11)


def even_better_hash_func(string):
    values = {'a': 3,
              'b': 5,
              'c': 7}

    # We use the sum function to sum the list
    value = sum(
        [values[ch]                     # This is list comprehension
            for ch in string            # It create a list, by iterating over
                if ch in values.keys()  # some iterable (like a list)
        ]                               # This is very similar to a for loop,
    )                                   # but it takes a value you produce each
                                        # iteration and adds that
                                        # to a new list that is returned by the
                                        # list comprehension.
    return "Hash is " + str(value % 11)
```

for more about list comprehension: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Answer (score 0):

It returns `None` because it doesn't return anything else. Stop printing the return value.